# API to get the role/roles required to access specific object in obiee catalog

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, analytics, obiee

Is there any API through which I can get the role(s) required to a specific object in catalog?

For example, if a user wants to see a particular analysis named 'cost analysis'. By passing the name or its path or attributes of that object(name,path) cost analysis.  Can I get the roles required for viewing the cost analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OBIEE SOAP "WebCatalogService Service" getItemInfo() Method to return all sorts of info about a catalog object, including ACL details.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e16364/methods.htm#BIEIT296

To use the API, you have to start with the SAWSessionService Service logon() method to get a session_id to pass in your getItemInfo request.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e16364/methods.htm#BIEIT240